# Storing Currency as Decimal in Cassandra and indexing via DSE Search (SolR)

Tags: solr, currency, bigdecimal, datastax-enterprise

I am using a decimal value type in cassandra to store money (corresponds to BigDecimal, a [reasonably precise number type for this use case](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/228584/why-is-bigdecimal-the-best-data-type-for-currency)).

I seem to be unable to index this field. The SolR data types I tried to match this are "[CurrencyField](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Currencies+and+Exchange+Rates)" and then float. The error message is nearly the same:

> Solr type text and Cassandra type: decimal do not match for field

CurrencyField seems to expect a currency and value as a tuple. This makes it necessary to store currency values as a string in C* to be able to index this correctly? As a workaround, I could store the values twice, as a decimal and string although I do not like the redundancy which complicates updates and other handling. Thanks for your suggestions...

Comment: not sure if BCDIntField will work

Answer (score 0):

Try using double or float. If you plan to do range scans use the trie Solr fields:

> TrieDoubleField   double
>
> TrieFloatField    float

Reference docs: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchSolrType.html

Comment: I want to store a precise representation of the number, check out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: It's not currently supported. You may want to have two fields for now.

Comment: @phact Do you know if and when the support will be added? With float, double, tfloat and tdouble, I get similar error messages:

    '''Solr type float and Cassandra type: decimal do not match for field: amount'''